# Django, Run fucntion after the user login / Register

Tags: python, django, authentication

Once a user registers on my site, I want run a function and after a user login I want to be able to run another function.

I want to know is anyway to do this apart from after the user logins redirects them to a view and once ive done what ive wanted redirect them again
Or is their a way i can overwrite the django register and login classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Auth signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals) from framework.